# Как заставить $routeProvider игнорировать ссылки с заглушками "#"?

Tags: angularjs, angular-routing

Проблема с выпадающим меню от Bootstrap.
При клике на дропдаун пункт меню http://joxi.ru/n2YkVqquo46Bzr срабатывает правило otherwise

```
$locationProvider.hashPrefix('!');
$routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo: '/main'});
```

и соответственно показывает view главной страницы.

В ссылке выпадающего меню стоит заглушка

```
href="#"
```

Пример верстки меню:

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
    <input class="search" type="text" placeholder="Search">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <li><a href="#!/main">Main<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#!/profile">Profile</a></li>
      <li><a href="#!/example"><i class="material-icons">face</i></a></li>
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Dropdown <span class="caret"></span>
        </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
          <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
          <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
```

Как побороть это и заставить игнорировать заглушки?
Нужно будет использовать также слайдеры, там будет такая же проблема...

Comment: добавь пример разметки в вопрос

Comment: пример ничем особенным не выделятся,
перекидывать на главную будет любая ссылка где есть # 

    <a href="#" ></a>

Comment: весь необходимый код, для воспроизведения ошибки должен быть непосредственно в вопросе. предоставленного кода не хватает. Плюс добавь ссылку на bootstrap который ты используешь

Comment: Bootstrap: v 3.3.7

Comment: добавь **ссылку** на bootstrap который ты используешь

Comment: Bootstrap лежит локально. Подтянул через Bower. Версия та же что и на офф. сайте последняя 3.3.7
http://getbootstrap.com/

Comment: используй bootstrap для ангуляра, например этот https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

Comment: Мой косяк, не уточнил что пишу на ангуляре 1.x Но, спасибо) про такое не знал. Сохранил на будущее.

Answer (score 0):

В `.run()` создаем наблюдателя за переходом и проверяем на наличие хэша.

```
 $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (event, toState) {
  var url = toState.url;
  if(url[0]=== '#') $event.preventDefault;
})
```